# "Mano a mano" in south America

Tags: expresiones

Are there additional meanings to "mano a mano" besides "going head to head" with someone? Especially, can "mano" take on a different meaning in this phrase from the standard meaning "hand"?

I have been told (by a spanish speaker, so no possible confusion stemming from the phonetic proximity to "man") that the expression "mano a mano" is used all over Latin America as "man to man", where "mano" is short for "hermano". Is this the case? Is it very common?

I did a google search, but didn't find much to confirm this, possibly because it may very well be mostly used as such in conversation and not in writing. What I did find was a facebook group under the name "[mano a mano por el hermano](https://www.facebook.com/Mano-a-mano-por-el-hermano-558364507644557/)" whose logo features pairs of multicolored hands reaching out to one another, which suggests that mano a mano was understood as "hand to hand".

**EDIT** apparently "hablar mano a mano" is one such time, when mano is to be understood as brother, or man. Can anyone confirm/infirm this interpretation? I've read it coming from a woman, so I have my doubts.

Comment: Maybe helps you know these other expressions: **Estamos a mano** = "before there was a debt or imbalance, but we are now at peace". **Está a la mano** = "is near or accessible".

Comment: @Rodrigo: in Argentina, your second expression would be "**está a mano**".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Mano a mano` means a competition where none of the participants have a clear advantage. It literally translates to `hand to hand` as in *combat*, but the "combat" could be sports, or some other amicable competition.

You could say

> Mi amigo y yo estábamos **mano a mano** apurando una botella de vodka a base de chupitos.

Note that in Spanish we use `hombro con hombro` to mean "fighting or working together".

While `mano` o `manito` stands for a shortened version of `hermano` in some latin american countries, I don't think that it relates to the `mano` of `mano a mano`. Even if you were told so by a native speaker, be aware that not all of us are masters of our own native languages (we all had to study our native languages to some extend, but that does not make us *professors* in our languages).

If you are interested, check the etymology of [Mano](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?mano). You'll see that it actually comes from a latin root that also means "power". Thus, the expression of `ask for her hand` when asking someone to marry you carries the connotation of gaining some power over her. `Mano a mano` would be "my power against yours".

`Mano a mano por el hermano` sound catchy as a slogan, but those people would be actually working "hombro con hombro" and not "mano a mano".

Comment: Thank you to the both of you (Diego and @Ustanak) for your replies! I was sceptical of this person's claim to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that comes from *hermano*. Actually, it's just the term for unarmed combat. (Of course, widely used.)
However, when it comes to competition stuff, the term is plenty used.

The other way that *mano a mano* is taken is with the well-known one ***face to face***.

---

For those who ever played video games, *mano a mano* is often used.